# xml starlet unattend

Tags: xml

o have some problem getting a specific value from an unattend.xml

i'm no really familiar with xslt so u wou like if some on can help

i posted the source xml on pastebin: http://pastebin.com/SgyH7A9z

i tried it already to get i with xpath since its the only node named "COmputerName" but i don't get anything.
xml sel -t -m //ComputerName -n unattend.xml

thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is probably because the <ComputerName> element is in a particular namespace, and XPath assumes that unqualified element names belong to the empty namespace. You must either establish a namespace context that maps a prefix to the namespace of the desired element (and I have no idea what tool you are using, so I cannot help you there), or you can be kind of lazy and select just on the "local" element name:

```
//*[local-name() = 'ComputerName']
```

i.e. select all elements that have a local name equal to 'ComputerName', irregardless of namespace belonging.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately it doesn't work.
As tool i'm using xml starlet as saying in the title ;) i tried to provide a namespace but i'm not ssure if i did it right because i don't understand the namespace thingy yet. xml sel -N x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:unattend" -t -m "//x:ComputerName" UNATTEND.xml

Comment: Ok, xmlstarlet, never heard of it. Anyway, it seems that instead ov the -m option, -v actually prints the selected stuff.